# ML program to find the acronyms of a given list

Tags: sml, ml

I am researching and learning about the ML language. I have met with a question and have difficulty in solving it. I'm sure I will use the Traverse, Size and Substring functions, but i cannot put it in some way, I'm a bit confused. Could you help?

Question:

```
val x = [ ["National", "Aeronautics", "and", "Space", "Administration"]
        , ["The", "North", "Atlantic", "Treaty", "Organization"]
        ]
```

Sample run:

```
val it = [ {acronym="NASA", name="National Aeronautics and Space Administration"},
         , {acronym="NATO", name="The North Atlantic Treaty Organization"}
         ]
       : nm list
```

Comment: What have you tried? What are you getting? We don't just write code for people.

Comment: I tried to solve. I wrote this type acro = { n:string, n1:string, n2:string, n3:string, n4:string, n5:string, n6:string, n7:string };




val h:acro = { n="National", n1="Aeronautics", n2="and", n3="Space", n4="Administration", n5="", n6="", n7="" };

val k:acro = { n="The", n1="North", n2="Atlantic", n3="Treaty", n4="Organization", n5="", n6="", n7="" };  but I can not combine it with functions.

Comment: It isn't quite clear what you are trying to do. What criterion are you using to discard the words "and" and "the" so that you don't end up with "NAASA" and "TNATO"?

Comment: Also -- trying to use a type for acronyms seems unmotivated. They are just strings and you just need to write a function which will take a list of strings and return a single string.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the information in your question, I'm guessing that the goal of the problem is to write a function `acronyms` which meets the following specification. I've taken some liberty of renaming types to make it clearer:

```
type words = string list
type summary = {acronym : string, name : string}

val acronyms : words list -> summary list
```

This function takes a list of organization names (which have been split into words) and produces a list of summaries. Each summary in the output describes the corresponding organization from the input.

The tricky part is writing a function `acronym : words -> summary` which computes a *single* summary. For example,

```
- acronym ["National", "Aeronautics", "and", "Space", "Administration"];
val it = {acronym="NASA",name="National Aeronautics and Space Administration"}
  : summary
```

Once you have this function, you can apply it to each organization name of the input with `List.map`:

```
fun acronyms orgs = List.map acronym orgs
```

I'll leave the `acronym` function to you. As a hint to get started, consider *filtering* the list of words to remove words such as "and" and "the".